# Natural logarithm question 1

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

i tried to derive logistic population model, and need to integrate this
$\int \frac{\frac{1}{k}}{1-\frac{N_t}{k}} dN_t$. here is my solution

$\int \frac{\frac{1}{k}}{1-\frac{N_t}{k}} dN_t=\int \frac{1}{k-N_t} dN_t=-\int \frac{1}{k-N_t}d{(k-N_t)}=-\ln\mid k-N_t\mid+C_1$. i think i have done something wrong here, because if i solve it this ways $\int \frac{\frac{1}{k}}{1-\frac{N_t}{k}} dN_t=-\int  \frac{1}{1-\frac{N_t}{k}} d(1-\frac{N_t}{k})=-\ln \mid 1-\frac{Nt}{k} \mid +C_2$ which is obviously different from the previous solution, so where is the mistake(s) ?

Comment: What about the constant of integration?

Comment: yeah i forget that @DonAntonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that
$$-\log\left(1-\frac1kx\right)=-\log\left(\frac1k\left(k-x\right)\right)=-\log(k-x)-\log\left(\frac1k\right),$$
and that $k$ is constant with respect to $x$, which shows that your antiderivatives differ by a constant, namely $-\log\left(1/k\right)$.

For more information look up [the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$\frac1k=-\left(\frac{N_t}{k}\right)'\implies -\int\frac{-\frac1k}{1-\frac{N_t}k}dN_t=-\log\left(1-\frac{N_t}k\right)+C=\log\frac k{k-N_t}+C$$